# Clarification on "unsigned int var : 1;" syntax

Tags: c++

I require some clarification regarding a particular assignment syntax I've found while browsing through the OpenGL Superbible source code. It's in the file sb6.h:

```
union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned int    fullscreen  : 1;
            unsigned int    vsync       : 1;
            unsigned int    cursor      : 1;
            unsigned int    stereo      : 1;
            unsigned int    debug       : 1;
        };
        unsigned int        all;
    } flags;
```

I have never seen this colon assignment before and would appreciate any input about this sort of assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not assignment; it's a bitfield.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field